# Tizen TV web application : Unexpected stop progress

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

I'm trying to run a sample TV web application on Samsung emulator but getting an error : `Unexpected stop progress...`

[image: error]
<sub>(source: [i.ibb.co](https://i.ibb.co/ygyHmWX/error.png))</sub>

Where **config.xml** is:-

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" id="http://yourdomain/HelloTizen" version="1.0.0" viewmodes="maximized"> <tizen:application id="AYtSQMvNTh.HelloTizen" package="AYtSQMvNTh" required_version="2.3"/> <content src="index.html"/> <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.all"/> <icon src="icon.png"/> <name>HelloTizen</name> <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch"/> <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/tv.inputdevice"/> <tizen:profile name="tv"/> <tizen:setting screen-orientation="portrait" context-menu="enable" background-support="disable" encryption="disable" install-location="auto" hwkey-event="enable"/> </widget>`

### Also not installing .wgt file in emulator

[image: err]
<sub>(source: [i.ibb.co](https://i.ibb.co/nznVq68/err.png))</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have the same problem.

Check if you can connect to emulator with `sdb shell` command. The `sdb.exe` is located in "tools" directory in Tizen Studio location.

If `sdb shell` return "closed" it means that emulator refuses connection.

I recommend to create "custom" emulator image:
Emulator Manager->Create->TV->tv-... (Custom)

### **EDIT :**

To run web application on new emulator You have to **change platform**.

in `config.xml`:

`<tizen:profile name="tv"/>`

to:
`<tizen:profile name="tv-samsung"/>`

and in `.tproject`:

```
<platform>
    <name>tv-5.0</name>
</platform>
```

to

```
<platform>
    <name>tv-samsung-5.0</name>
</platform>
```

Or when You create new project:

New project -> template -> Custom(extended) -> choose TV-samsung v5.0 from dropdown.